# Does jQuery event.stopPropagation() stop all callbacks for that event, or just the one it's declared in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, jquery-events

I have a question about jQuery's `event.stopPropagation()`. Does `event.stopPropagation()` prevent all callback functions for that event on that target element (not necessarily the same target but same parent) from bubbling to the parent or just the one it's declared in? To elaborate, say I have this:

```
$('#someId').on('mousedown touchstart MSPointerDown', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(e.target).toggleClass('blue');
});
$('#someId').on('mousedown touchstart MSPointerDown', function(e){
    $(e.target).toggleClass('blue');
});
```

or

```
$('#someId').children()[0].on('mousedown touchstart MSPointerDown', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(e.target).toggleClass('blue');
});
$('#someId').children()[1].on('mousedown touchstart MSPointerDown', function(e){
    $(e.target).toggleClass('blue');
});
```

Or would I need to have `e.stopPropagation()` in both to prevent the callback form bubbling up?

Comment: It stops the event from propagating, that's it. All events on the current element will still fire. So, yes, it will stop that event from reaching ancestor elements, but it will not stop other events that are bound on the same element for that same event. For that, use stopImmediatePropagation. Sibling elements are not affected in either case.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'm asking about on the same event, so I should be good with stopPropagation, so long as it stops all callbaks for that event, which does it stop all callbacks for that event?  But what about the second example? Where it's two different targets but same parent, would I need stopPropagation in both callbacks?

Comment: No, it doesn't stop all callbacks. *It stops it from propagating to ancestor elements*. To stop all callbacks, use stopImmediatePropagation too.

Comment: Second example, yes, the parent is irrelevant in this case since the event is bound directly to the child element. You will need to treat each one as separate events on separate elements that are not related in any way.

Comment: Ok thanks, would you wanna leave this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example, the two events are not related at all, so you will have to treat them as such; they will both need to be prevented.

`stopPropagation` will stop the event from propagating up the dom, but it will not stop other event handlers bound to the same element and event. For that, you would need `stopImmediatePropagation`.